# JsTree layout brokes when used inside Materialize's SideNav

Tags: html, css, materialize, jstree

I'm trying to use a jstree inside a sidenav from Materialize. The jstree works pretty fine outside the sidenav but misalign inside it.

Here is a comparison:

[Aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAcHa.png)

[Misaligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBrhb.png)

Here is the main HTML code:

```
<div id="slide-out" class="side-nav">
    <div id="jstree"></div>
</div>
```

Also here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0bdrhokg/19/

Answer (score 0):

This problem is because of Materializecss default value for `display` in `.side-nav li > a` path.
Add this to your css :

```
.side-nav li > a {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

Materializecss default value for `display` was `block` that cause the problem.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0bdrhokg/46/)

Comment: It worked, but there are still some problems. First I changed the padding value to 0 to proper align in the left. But if I add jstree's contextmenu plugin, the box opened is not at the same position as the mouse was clicked. [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0bdrhokg/55/)

Comment: I can't see the problem. do you added plugin to jsfiddle link?

Comment: I added other link at the end of my previous comment. Right click over a node and you will see.